# Deleting the last octets of an IP address

Tags: regex, python-3.x, split, ip

This is my code:

```
ip = ("192.143.234.543/23 
       192.143.234.5/23 
       192.143.234.23/23")

separateOct = (".")
ipNo4Oct = line.split(separateOct, 1) [0] 
print (ipNo4Oct)
```

The IPs come from a text file and I have done my for loops right.

The result I get is:

```
192
192
192
```

But I want this result:

```
192.143.234
192.143.234
192.143.234
```

How do I get the result I want?

Comment: What is `line`? (I know it, but I want to show that your code is incomplete...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
ip = ("192.143.234.543/23",
       "192.143.234.5/23",
       "192.143.234.23/23")

for line in ip:
    separator = "."
    ipNo4Oct = separator.join(line.split(separator, 3)[:-1])
    print (ipNo4Oct)
```

you re-join your 3 parts using the separator.

Comment: Thanks! @glglgl it worked fine! Sorry for not posting the whole script, I'm new to this forum! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use almost the same code, with some slicing and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> ipNo4Oct = ip.split(separateOct) [0:3]
>>> '.'.join(ipNo4Oct)
'192.143.234'
```

Or for the entire string (considering it can be splitted to lines as your code suggests):

```
>>> for line in ip:
        ipNo4Oct = line.split(separateOct) [0:3]
        '.'.join(ipNo4Oct)

'192.143.234'
'192.143.234'
'192.143.234'
```